# Error while trying to connect to sql server with python using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to sql server from a different computer. I'm using the following code. The odbc driver is installed and also pyodbc is installed.

```
import pyodbc 

server = 'SERVER'
database = 'DBNAME' 
username = 'SA' 
password = 'SQLPWD' 
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

However I'm receiving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL 
Server]Login failed for user 'SA'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC 
Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'SA'. (18456)")
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and the older questions have not been much helpful. I'm new to Python.

Comment: Personally I recommend not using the `sa` account for your application. Also find out what the real error is from the SQL Server logs and then post that in an [edit].

Comment: Check if your password, server address and db name are correct. Take a look on the sql server and check if the [sa user is enabled](https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/) and the connection mode is set to mixed mode (allow windows and other connection). Check qith sql configuration manager that you [sql is opened on the port 1433 on the right ip address, also configure the firwall rules.](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)

Comment: Does the password contain a semicolon (`;`) or curly brackets (`{` or `}`)?

Comment: @GordThompson the password contains a # and $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is related to:

- SA access disabled ([REFERENCE](https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/))
- Wrong Server Authentication Selection ([REFERENCE](https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/))
- SQL Server is not open for remote access ([REFERENCE](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/))

You can use [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) to manage your server configuration.

**IMPORTANT**: As suggested by @Larnu is not a good idea use the `sa` user for remote access, create new user with limited access to the database & table is a better way to manage the server and secure it. Take a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39126/215090) to better understand.

### SA Access disabled

To enable it you have to do:

- Connect to your server with SSMS (Using the **Windows Authentication**)

  [image: Connection]
- Open the *Security* --> *Logins* Section and double click on the user `sa`

  [image: SaConfig]
- Open the page *General* type a *Password* and *Confirm Password*, go in the page *Status* and set the *Login* on **Enabled**.

  [image: GeneralStatusChange]

### Wrong Server Authentication Selection

- In the Object Explorer **right-click on the server instance** and open the *Properties*

  [image: ServerProp]
- Open the page *Security* and check the option *SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode*

  [image: SecType]

### SQL Server is not open for remote access

- In the Object Explorer **right-click on the server instance** and open the *Properties*
- Open the page *Connections* and check *Allow remote connections to this server*

  [image: CheckRemote]
- Open your *Start Menu* and search for *SQL Server Configuration Manager*
- Under the *SQL Server Network Configuration* select *Protocols for*
- Double-Click on *TCP/IP* and croll to the buttom, set the *TCP Port* to `1433`
- In the left pane of *SQL Server Configuration Manager* click *SQL Server Services*, right-click *SQL Server<instance_name>*, and click Restart.

Now the issues should be solved, if not take a look on how to add a rule to windows firewall in the section **Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access** of the [reference](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)