# Getting error while connecting to sql server using pyodbc in databricks 10.4 LTS runtime

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, databricks, pyodbc

Please  Help...

Im getting below error while trying to connect to sql server with databricks runtime 10.4 LTS , while the connection was successfull with databricks runtime 7.4 LTS

Error:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I'm using below installation steps in an init script

```
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/driversqlodbc.sh", """
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc """, True)
```

And my connection string is like this

```
odbc_driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+odbc_driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+db_user+';PWD='+ password,autocommit=True)
```

** EDIT **

Below is the output of  `cat /etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Now my script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

And Connection String

```
odbc_driver= '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+odbc_driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+',1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+db_user+';PWD='+ password,autocommit=True)
```

Comment: could this be an answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64223277/17637655

Comment: I checked all the settings mentioned in this link. They are enabled. Im still unable to connect

Comment: You need to open the firewall for port 1433 I think

Comment: It is open and Im able to connect with databricks runtime 7.4 LTS, with 10.4 LTS its failing

Comment: Aside... `PORT=1433;` isn't a connection string parameter. You'd normally use `SERVER=tcp:serverNameOrIpAddress,portNumber;` (note the comma), but specifying port 1433 isn't required because it's the default port.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73020682/edit) your question to include the output of `cat /etc/os-release`. If you're using Databricks 10.4 LTS then I'd expect it to be running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. That being the case you're referencing an incorrect repo at packages.microsoft.com.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have edited my question, Also tried with the connection string you suggested, Unable to connect

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an issue with the *pyodbc* version.  We had the same problem.  The latest *pyodbc* update to pyodbc==4.0.34 (5 days ago) causes some issues, see https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1079 for example.

So we changed the following line in *setup.py*:

```
"pyodbc~=4.0.32",
```

to

```
"pyodbc==4.0.32",
```

Note the double == sign. It works with 4.0.32 for us.

Comment: Are you using msodbcsql17 or msodbcsql18?

Comment: [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1